# Should response Content-Type always be same as Accept?

Tags: rest, http

I have a resource with an original version of the entity format and a later, improved version with breaking changes.

The caller opts into later versions using the `Accept` header.

Pretend for a moment that my service only returns JSON.

Should the response be `application/json` or exactly the format in the `Accept` header? Does anyone care if I cheat?

For example, is this good or bad:

- Client request: `GET /people/1; Accept: application/vnd.personv2+json`
- Server response: `200 { "Name": "John" }; Content-Type: application/json`

The server has presented a v2 person format using JSON, but has said that its "just" normal application JSON, as opposed to saying its exactly the format requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `accept` marks what sort of content endpoint can handle. Can the endpoint deal with json? xml? img? html? etc... More formally:

> The Accept request-header field can be used to specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response. Accept headers can be used to indicate that the request is specifically limited to a small set of desired types, as in the case of a request for an in-line image.

The `content-type` is what the response has in its payload in order for the request initiator to know how to handle. And formally:

> The Content-Type entity-header field indicates the media type of the entity-body sent to the recipient or, in the case of the HEAD method, the media type that would have been sent had the request been a GET.

For example - you have an endpoint in your web-server that accepts json (for example - client's data `{'name': 'some-name', 'age': '30'}`) and returns an image (for example - a descriptive image for people in age 30). In this case the accept will be `application/json` and the response something like `img/*`

This also applies to your case. The accept is one thing, the content-type is another. They do not have to be the same even if they semantically are.

Answer (score 3):

[RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) is pretty clear on this:

> If the [accept] header field is
> present in a request and none of the available representations for
> the response have a media type that is listed as acceptable, the
> origin server can either

> - honor the header field by sending a 406 (Not
>   Acceptable) response or

- disregard the header field by treating the
  response as if it is not subject to content negotiation.

Formatting mine.

So yes, what you're asking (*"Return `application/json` when the client requested `application/vnd.personv2+json`)"* is just fine.